# Book Style of Classical thesis

Tags: classicthesis, book-design

I am using the classical thesis for my PhD thesis and I realized that the style will produce A4 instead of book style. I found these comments in classicalthesis.sty, it is a bit confusing to me and how I can change it to the book style. Thanks

```
\DeclareBoolOption{a4paper}
\DeclareBoolOption{a5paper}
\DeclareBoolOption{b5paper}
\DeclareBoolOption{letterpaper}
\DeclareStringOption[a4]{paper} % paper size defaults to A4
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{ct}


%%% seems that KOMA-Script gives preference to old-style paper options,    thus first
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@letterpaper}}{\renewcommand*{\ct@paper}  {letter}}{}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@a5paper}}{\renewcommand*{\ct@paper}{a5}}{}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@b5paper}}{\renewcommand*{\ct@paper}{b5}}{}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@a4paper}}{\renewcommand*{\ct@paper}{a4}}{}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\ct@paper}{letter}\OR\equal{\ct@paper}{a5}\OR   \equal{\ct@paper}{b5}\OR\equal{\ct@paper}{a4}}{\relax}%
 {\PackageWarningNoLine{classicthesis}{Text area setup only provided  for paper sizes: letter, a5, b5, a4. You are using paper=\ct@paper}}
```

And,

```
% ********************************************************************
% Textblock size
%*******************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{headinclude,footinclude}{typearea} % for classes    other than KOMA
\RequirePackage{typearea}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\ct@paper}{letter}}%
    {% Letter 216mm x 279mm
        \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{letter paper, Palatino or other}
        \areaset[current]{356pt}{700pt}%  guessing from A4 values
        \setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
        \setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
}{\relax}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ct@paper}{b5}}%
{% B5 176mm x 250mm
        % Thanks to Jos\'e M. Alcaide
        \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{B5 paper, Palatino or other}%
        \areaset[current]{311pt}{645pt}%
        \setlength{\marginparwidth}{6em}%
        \setlength{\marginparsep}{1.5em}%
}{\relax}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\ct@paper}{a5}}%
{% A5 148mm x 210mm
        \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{A5 paper, Palatino or other}%
        \areaset[current]{288pt}{555pt}%
        \setlength{\marginparwidth}{4em}%
        \setlength{\marginparsep}{1.25em}%
}{\relax}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\ct@paper}{a4}}%
{% A4 210mm x 297mm
        \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{A4 paper, Palatino or other}
        \areaset[current]{336pt}{750pt} % ~ 336 * factor 2 + 33 head +  42 \the\footskip
        % \areaset{336pt}{761pt} % 686 (factor 2.2) + 33 head + 42 head   \the\footskip 10pt
        \setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
        \setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
}{\relax}
```

Comment: Why not much more simply `\PassOptionsToClass{letter}` (or something like this) just before `\documentclass[]{}` ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `classicthesis` package, not the class for that, and tweak the page size settings with `geometry`and with other of the main class' options.

For instance, you could use the standard `book` class for that:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders, parts, pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[paper=b5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Note the class option `twoside`and the settings chosen for paper size in `geometry`; I chose the predefined b5 paper size (148 × 210mm), as it is a good "book size", but you can choose what best suits you. (The `lipsum` package just fills the document with dummy text.)

[image: first page]
[image: second page]